# Using std::transform and tr1::bind to transform a vector of std::complex

Tags: c++, bind, transform, complex-numbers

Given a std::vector of std::complex, I would like to transform it to a vector containing only the real part of the complex, divided by some constant coefficient.
Right now, I do that:

```
std::vector<std::complex<double> > vec;
std::vector<double> realVec;
double norm = 2.0;
...
for (std::vector<std::complex<double> >::iterator it = vec.begin(), itEnd = vec.end(); it != itEnd; ++it)
    realVec.push_back((*it).real() / norm);
```

This works fine of course, but I am looking for a way to use std::transform to do the same thing. I tried:

```
transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), back_inserter(realVec), tr1::bind(divides<double>(), tr1::bind(&complex<double>::real, tr1::placeholders::_1), norm));
```

But it won't work. I have this error:

```
erreur: no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::tr1::_Placeholder<1>&)’|
```

I don't understand why there is a "unresolved overloaded function type".

Could someone explain to me what is wrong?

Comment: I know this is probably heresy, but IMO the version using the for loop is much clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this, at least not directly.  The types of Standard Library member functions (like `complex<double>::real`) are left unspecified, so an implementation may provide additional overloads and the functions that are there may have additional parameters with default arguments.

In effect, there is no portable way to take the address of a Standard Library member function.

Your best bet would be to write a helper function:

```
template <typename T>
T get_real(const std::complex<T>& c) { return c.real(); }
```

and bind to that:

```
std::tr1::bind(&get_real<double>, std::tr1::placeholders::_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::complex<>::real()` is overloaded (cf. C++11 [complex]).

```
template <typename T>
class complex {
    // ...
    T real() const; // getter
    void real( T ); // setter
    // ...
};
```

C++ requires a disambiguation when you take the address of an overloaded function. In your case, you have to say:

```
tr1::bind( static_cast<double(std::complex<double>::*)()const>( &std::complex<double>::real ),
           tr1::placeholders::_1 )
```

Yes, this is ugly.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that easy, since an implementation is allowed to provide additional overloads or add additional parameters with default arguments to the existing overloads.  :(

Comment: @James: sure, but OP asked _why_ he got that error. Legalese is nice, but saying "you can't name the types of member functions of classes in namespace std" misses the point of the OP's question, IMO, which is the disambiguation needed when taking the address of an overloaded function.

Answer (score 0):

For C++11, you can write

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <complex>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const std::vector<std::complex<double>> vec = {std::complex<double>(1, 0), std::complex<double>(0, 1)};
    std::vector<double> real_vec;
    constexpr double norm = 2.0;
    std::transform(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), std::back_inserter(real_vec), std::bind(std::divides<double>(), std::bind<double (*)(const std::complex<double> &)>(std::real, std::placeholders::_1), norm));
    for (const auto &elem : real_vec)
        std::cout << elem << '\n';
}
```

You can simplify by `using F = double (*)(const std::complex<double> &)` and write `std::bind<F>(std::real, std::placeholders::_1)`. Since C++14, the template type argument for the standard operator templates can generally be omitted, so you can write `std::divides<>()`.